# How to pass session id from one page to another in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am using a datagridview. I am using a command field & want to pass a session id (which is stored in database) from one page to another as I click on the command field link.

Comment: In all honesty I don't think either of us knows what you're talking about. The term "Sessions" in ASP.Net usually refer to the session object that allows you to cater information around the site automatically. There are very very rare cases where you should ever need the session id. You might have to go back to square one and look up the proper terms and describe your whole situation using the proper terms in order for anyone to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

use **[HttpContext Items collection](http://odetocode.com/Articles/111.aspx)**.

```
Context.Items["MyVariable"] = myValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [**`Session`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) Object

```
longID = ...// from DB
HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] = ID;
```

Comment: Session objects are not intended for passing values from one page to another. They are used to store session specific data.

Comment: you are right, but he is working over 'session id'. looks the ID in use is specific per session.